# Java Swing GUI Invisible

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, invisible

basically I have a very simple GUI, but for some reason when I run the code the JButtons only appear when I mouse over them, and the JTextField only appear if I click on them. How do I fix this so that they are visible when the program runs? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
    //JFrame + settings
    JFrame frmFormSubmission = new JFrame();

    frmFormSubmission.setSize(new Dimension(350, 165));
    frmFormSubmission.setTitle("Form Submission - Client");
    frmFormSubmission.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frmFormSubmission.setVisible(true);
    frmFormSubmission.setResizable(false);
    frmFormSubmission.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //JPanel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frmFormSubmission.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    //JLabels
    //Name
    JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
    lblName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    lblName.setBounds(46, 12, 40, 14);
    panel.add(lblName);

    //Address
    JLabel lblAddress = new JLabel("Address:");
    lblAddress.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    lblAddress.setBounds(33, 37, 53, 14);
    panel.add(lblAddress);

    //Phone
    JLabel lblPhone = new JLabel("Phone #:");
    lblPhone.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    lblPhone.setBounds(28, 62, 58, 14);
    panel.add(lblPhone);

    //Email
    JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("Email:");
    lblEmail.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    lblEmail.setBounds(46, 87, 36, 14);
    panel.add(lblEmail);

    //JTextFields
    //Name
    nameField = new JTextField();
    nameField.setBounds(93, 11, 137, 20);
    panel.add(nameField);
    nameField.setColumns(10);

    //Address
    addressField = new JTextField();
    addressField.setColumns(10);
    addressField.setBounds(93, 36, 137, 20);
    panel.add(addressField);

    //Phone
    phoneField = new JTextField();
    phoneField.setColumns(10);
    phoneField.setBounds(93, 61, 137, 20);
    panel.add(phoneField);

    //Email
    emailField = new JTextField();
    emailField.setColumns(10);
    emailField.setBounds(93, 86, 137, 20);
    panel.add(emailField);

    //JButtons
    //Submit
    JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    btnSubmit.setBounds(240, 10, 89, 23);
    panel.add(btnSubmit);

    //Cancel
    JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    btnCancel.setBounds(240, 44, 89, 23);
    panel.add(btnCancel);

    //Flush
    JButton btnFlush = new JButton("Flush");
    btnFlush.setBounds(240, 76, 89, 23);
    panel.add(btnFlush);

    //Checkbox
    JCheckBox chckbxPromotions = new JCheckBox("Email me with new and promotions!");
    chckbxPromotions.setBounds(25, 108, 205, 23);
    panel.add(chckbxPromotions);
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: FWIW, I tweaked your code to be compilable ([see here](http://pastebin.com/LiP3fTsA)) and I tested it in Netbeans 8, but I could not replicate your display error. [It looked correct to me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2FdFK.png).

Comment: Ah, when I edited my local copy of your code I instantiated the JFrame on the AWT Event Queue thread as a matter of habit. When I did it on the main thread instead, I was able to replicate your issue. It isn't clear in your question which thread you used, but you shouldn't be doing any GUI init or updates on the main thread—use something like [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `frmFormSubmission.setVisible(true);` as the last thing you do. setVisible will layout your components so they can be properly drawn. If you add components without laying them out, then you'll have graphical issues.

For more information on what that means, check out the documentation on the [validate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate--) method.

Answer (score 0):

Also, try

```
frmFormSubmission.invalidate();
frmFormSubmission.validate();
frmFormSubmission.repaint();
```

If this still does not work, you can try this:

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frmFormSubmission);
```